# Validate vs ValidateAsync

Tags: fluentvalidation

In FluentValidation, there are two versions of validate method: Validate and ValidateAsync.

I am confused by the async version, why we need this in the normal validation API. I think async would be useless in CPU bound operations and it looks like this validate would not involve any IO stuff.

Is there any scenario that we would use async version instead of the sync version ?

Comment: What if you want to validate against a database?

Comment: @YuanZ I'm glad you asked this question I was asking myself the same thing

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/async.html), the asynchronous version should be called whenever you have custom rules defined with `MustAsync` or `CustomAsync`, as well as defining asynchronous conditions with `WhenAsync`.
Here is an example:

```cs
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  SomeExternalWebApiClient _client;

  public CustomerValidator(SomeExternalWebApiClient client) {
    _client = client;

    RuleFor(x => x.Id).MustAsync(async (id, cancellation) => {
      bool exists = await _client.IdExists(id);
      return !exists;
    }).WithMessage("ID Must be unique");
  }
}
```

It is also important to understand that you **should not** use asynchronous rules when using [automatic validation with ASP.NET](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html) as ASP.NET’s validation pipeline is not asynchronous. If you use asynchronous rules with ASP.NET’s automatic validation, they will always be run synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use the async version to check the validation with server, for example, to check if the email or password is unique.